# is it not possible to schedule aws-sns?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am developing IOS and node.js application. And I want to use the push-notifications service. Finally, I decided to use Amazon's sns service.
And I want to send a push service to all registered devices at a specific time, one at a time. I do not know if Amazon's sns service can do it. Is this possible? If not, would I be better off using Firebases?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html). CloudWatch Events can invoke a SNS topic on a schedule that is user defined.